# Esd protected workstation - How can I test my workstation for static?

Tags: circuit, integrated

I have just set up my first esd workstation for my integrated circuits. It has a grounded 2 layer mat and a wrist strap. I have tested the resistance of the mat cord, the conductive layer of my mat, the wrist cord and the wrist strap using a multimeter as well as the outlet using an outlet tester. How can I test that I am discharged and there is no esd from me to my circuit? How can I test that the outlets ground wire is the real ground and is not just wired to neutral?
Thanks!
Update:  I have now tested the ground wiring for a ac voltage difference with a gas pipe and a water pipe.  Both have a small stable voltage difference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as ESD goes, it's all about relative charge. If your circuits are on the mat, and your wrist strap is tied to the mat/mat's ground, then you're all set because your potential charge, your mat's potential charge, and your electronics potential charge will all be the exact same so no charge will flow.

I assume you're living in the USA...

By code, ground and neutral are bonded at the main breaker box so that's not really a concern.

You can easily test your outlet with a volt meter. Hot (small slot) to Neutral (large slot) should read approximately 120v. Hot to ground (roundish hole) should read 120v. Neutral to Ground should read virtually nothing, though a volt or two is acceptable.

Comment: Yes, but it's importants to get the voltage low for esd.  You would get those same test results if the ground wire was just neutral and didn't go into the ground.